# How to get the number of files in a directory with Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

How can I get the count for the number of files in a directory using Camel?

Thanks

Comment: Write a bean to do it?

Comment: Yeah you can use java.io.File to return the list of files, and then get the size of that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to do this with Camel - the following is an example:

```
// add our route to the CamelContext
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {

            from("file:"+getFullPath()+"?noop=true")
            .process(new Processor() {

                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                    System.out.println("size is #" +exchange.getProperty("CamelBatchSize"));
                    System.out.println(file.getName());

                }
            }).to("file:/home/anton/tmp/outbox?"); 

        }
    });
```

Comment: Any idea,how to do the same in blueprint?